# C++ vector and struct problem win32

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, struct

I have a structure  defined in my header file:

```
struct video
{
 wchar_t* videoName;
 std::vector<wchar_t*> audio;
 std::vector<wchar_t*> subs;
};
struct ret
{
std::vector<video*> videos;
wchar_t* errMessage;
};
struct params{
 HWND form;
 wchar_t* cwd;
 wchar_t* disk;
 ret* returnData;
};
```

When I try to add my video structure to a vector of video* I get access violation reading 0xcdcdcdc1 (videoName is @ 0xcdcdcdcd, before I allocate it)

```
//extract of code where problem is
video v;
v.videoName = (wchar_t*)malloc((wcslen(line)+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
wcscpy(v.videoName,line);
p->returnData->videos.push_back(&v); //error here
```

Comment: You have allocated `p->returnData = new ret()`? In any case it looks like you're creating `v` on the stack and then storing a pointer to it in your vector; that won't outlive the current function so if it is returned elsewhere you'll need to `video* v = new video()` instead.

Comment: Too many pointers. :( You're passing `&v` into a vector...the address of something that will go out of scope! You should just change your vector to `std::vector<video>` and `push_back(v)`. Also, why not use `std::string`? And you probably haven't allocated a `new ret` for `returnData`. Why use so many pointers? Your life would be much simpler without them. Only use dynamic allocation when you really have to.

Comment: You probably want `std::wstring` as a replacement for the `wchar_t` pointers.

Comment: I want to use as little classes as possible, I don't like wstring//string because they are heavy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that either `p` or `p->returnData` is an uninitialized/invalid pointer.

Also, this isn't causing your crash, but it will once you fix the current problem: beware of returning the pointer to a local variable. Once your function goes out of scope the local vector will be destroyed and `&v` will be an invalid pointer. If you want your vector to exist beyond the scope of the current function then you will need to allocate it on the heap:

```
vector *v = new video();
...
p->returnData->videos.push_back(v);
```

Comment: Additionally he adds a pointer to a local variable which may also cause problems!

Comment: The real solution is to ditch the pointers. There's no purpose of using them but to create extra work.

Comment: Thanks the p->returnData= (ret*)malloc(sizeof(ret));
wasn't the right way of doing it, I did a new ret() and it worked great

Comment: Also I need pointers because this is in a thread and am going to pass it back to the other thread that's the reason for so many pointers

Comment: @james: You only need one pointer, then. Just return a pointer to an allocated "return data" structure, *nothing else needs to be a pointer.*

Comment: thanks for pointing that out I created a new video pointer so wouldn't go out of scope